# Identify 19-pin connector that looks like USB micro

Tags: connector, identification

We use a satellite modem that sports a 19-pin connector. There is a handy connector on the board to let us communicate with it, but the supplier doesn't know what brand/model the connector is, and the manufacturer is incommunicado. We're reduced to using a proprietary $50 cable that mates with it and terminates in fly-leads that we have to manually solder. Can you help?

At first it looks like a standard USB micro, but on closer inspection it has 19 very compact contacts (10 on top, 9 below). Here are some photos of both ends:

[image: PCB Connector view 1]
[image: PCB Connector view 2]
[image: Cable Connector view 1]
[image: Cable Connector view 2]

It would be super if you could identify manufacturer and part number or series.

Comment: It's almost definitely Micro HDMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDMI Type D, aka Micro HDMI. Has the same signal set as regular HDMI. There are adapters and cables to go to regular HDMI that might make your life easier.

That said, they probably repurposed the pinout to their own use, so you'll need to reverse engineer that. But it'd be really lame if they didn't re-use the diff pairs.